# Editing the retrieved String from parsed JSON string

Tags: java, android, json

My code for book list runs well so far.  I'm going to make URL requests later, I'm just working on the functionality at the moment.  However, here is the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR3VB.jpg) of my output. What it does is that for my authors section, the name of the author is printed in square bracked and the maturity rating is printed in capital letters with an underscore.  I haven't been able to figure out how to edit my output in a way that is more user friendly.

Here are my Java classes.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Books> books = BookUtils.extractBooks();

        // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
        ListView bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of earthquakes
        BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(this, books);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        bookListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

BookAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {

    public BookAdapter(Context context, List<Books> books){
        super(context, 0, books);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Books currentBook = getItem(position);

        TextView title = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        title.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

        TextView authors = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        authors.setText(currentBook.getAuthors());

        TextView publisher = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_publisher);
        publisher.setText(currentBook.getPublisher());

        TextView publishingDate = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_publishing_date);
        publishingDate.setText(currentBook.getPublishedDate());

        TextView language = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_language);
        language.setText(currentBook.getLanguage());

        TextView pageCount = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_page_count);
        pageCount.setText(currentBook.getCount());

        TextView printType = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_print_type);
        printType.setText(currentBook.getPrintType());

        TextView maturityRating = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_maturity_rating);
        maturityRating.setText(currentBook.getMaturityRating());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

Books.java

```
public class Books {
    private String mTitle;
    private String mAuthors;

    private String mPublisher;
    private String mPublishingDate;
    private String mLanguage;

    private String mCount;
    private String mPrintType;
    private String mMaturityRating;

    public Books(String title, String authors, String publisher, String publishingDate, String language, String count, String printType, String maturityRating) {
        mTitle = title;
        mAuthors = authors;

        mPublisher = publisher;
        mPublishingDate = publishingDate;
        mLanguage = language;

        mCount = count;
        mPrintType = printType;
        mMaturityRating = maturityRating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {return mTitle;}
    public String getAuthors(){return mAuthors;}

    public String getPublisher(){return mPublisher;}
    public String getPublishedDate(){return mPublishingDate;}
    public String getLanguage(){return mLanguage;}

    public String getCount(){return mCount;}
    public String getPrintType(){return mPrintType;}
    public String getMaturityRating(){return mMaturityRating;}
}
```

BookUtils.java

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class BookUtils {

    private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\n" +
            " \"kind\": \"books#volumes\",\n" +
            " \"totalItems\": 1117,\n" +
            " \"items\": [\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "   \"kind\": \"books#volume\",\n" +
            "   \"id\": \"IEk2m00o9_IC\",\n" +
            "   \"etag\": \"+odAmEu8Vk0\",\n" +
            "   \"selfLink\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/IEk2m00o9_IC\",\n" +
            "   \"volumeInfo\": {\n" +
            "    \"title\": \"Android Apps Security\",\n" +
            "    \"authors\": [\n" +
            "     \"Sheran Gunasekera\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"publisher\": \"Apress\",\n" +
            "    \"publishedDate\": \"2012-09-12\",\n" +
            "    \"description\": \"Android Apps Security provides guiding principles for how to best design and " +
            "develop Android apps with security in mind. It explores concepts that can be used to secure apps and how " +
            "developers can use and incorporate these security features into their apps. This book will provide developers with " +
            "the information they need to design useful, high-performing, and secure apps that expose end-users to as little risk " +
            "as possible. Overview of Android OS versions, features, architecture and security. Detailed examination of areas where " +
            "attacks on applications can take place and what controls should be implemented to protect private user data In-depth guide " +
            "to data encryption, authentication techniques, enterprise security and applied real-world examples of these concepts What you’ll " +
            "learn How to identify data that should be secured How to use the Android APIs to ensure confidentiality and integrity of data " +
            "How to build secure apps for the enterprise About Public Key Infrastructure, encryption APIs and how to implement them in apps " +
            "About owners, access control lists and permissions to allow user control over App properties About client-server apps and how to manage " +
            "authentication, transport layer encryption and server-side security Who this book is for This book is for intermediate and experienced Android " +
            "app developers that are already familiar with writing apps from scratch. It discusses mechanisms on how apps can be secured so that private, end-user " +
            "data is kept secure on the device and while in transit. If you’re just embarking on the path to Android development, then this book " +
            "may prove to be a useful companion to other developer guides. Table of Contents Android Architecture & Security Controls " +
            "The Foundation of an App Who Has Access? Designing and Developing 3 Sample Apps Using PKI & Encryption Interfacing with Web " +
            "Services Writing for the Enterprise Designing and Developing 3 More Sample Apps Publishing and Selling Your Apps Malware, Spyware " +
            "and Your End-User API Reference\",\n" +
            "    \"industryIdentifiers\": [\n" +
            "     {\n" +
            "      \"type\": \"ISBN_13\",\n" +
            "      \"identifier\": \"9781430240624\"\n" +
            "     },\n" +
            "     {\n" +
            "      \"type\": \"ISBN_10\",\n" +
            "      \"identifier\": \"1430240628\"\n" +
            "     }\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"readingModes\": {\n" +
            "     \"text\": true,\n" +
            "     \"image\": true\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"pageCount\": 248,\n" +
            "    \"printType\": \"BOOK\",\n" +
            "    \"categories\": [\n" +
            "     \"Computers\"\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"maturityRating\": \"NOT_MATURE\",\n" +
            "    \"allowAnonLogging\": true,\n" +
            "    \"contentVersion\": \"1.1.1.0.preview.3\",\n" +
            "    \"imageLinks\": {\n" +
            "     \"smallThumbnail\": \"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api\",\n" +
            "     \"thumbnail\": \"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"language\": \"en\",\n" +
            "    \"previewLink\": \"http://books.google.ca/books?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=android&hl=&cd=1&source=gbs_api\",\n" +
            "    \"infoLink\": \"http://books.google.ca/books?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&dq=android&hl=&source=gbs_api\",\n" +
            "    \"canonicalVolumeLink\": \"http://books.google.ca/books/about/Android_Apps_Security.html?hl=&id=IEk2m00o9_IC\"\n" +
            "   },\n" +
            "   \"saleInfo\": {\n" +
            "    \"country\": \"CA\",\n" +
            "    \"saleability\": \"NOT_FOR_SALE\",\n" +
            "    \"isEbook\": false\n" +
            "   },\n" +
            "   \"accessInfo\": {\n" +
            "    \"country\": \"CA\",\n" +
            "    \"viewability\": \"PARTIAL\",\n" +
            "    \"embeddable\": true,\n" +
            "    \"publicDomain\": false,\n" +
            "    \"textToSpeechPermission\": \"ALLOWED\",\n" +
            "    \"epub\": {\n" +
            "     \"isAvailable\": true,\n" +
            "     \"acsTokenLink\": \"http://books.google.ca/books/download/Android_Apps_Security-sample-epub.acsm?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&format=epub&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"pdf\": {\n" +
            "     \"isAvailable\": true,\n" +
            "     \"acsTokenLink\": \"http://books.google.ca/books/download/Android_Apps_Security-sample-pdf.acsm?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&format=pdf&output=acs4_fulfillment_token&dl_type=sample&source=gbs_api\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"webReaderLink\": \"http://books.google.ca/books/reader?id=IEk2m00o9_IC&hl=&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_api\",\n" +
            "    \"accessViewStatus\": \"SAMPLE\",\n" +
            "    \"quoteSharingAllowed\": false\n" +
            "   },\n" +
            "   \"searchInfo\": {\n" +
            "    \"textSnippet\": \"This book will provide developers with the information they need to design useful, high-performing, and secure apps that expose end-users to as little risk as possible. Overview of Android OS versions, features, architecture and security.\"\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            " ]\n" +
            "}";
    private BookUtils() {
    }

    public static ArrayList<Books>extractBooks(){
        ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
            JSONArray booksArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

            for(int i = 0; i < booksArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject currentBook = booksArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                String authors = volumeInfo.getString("authors");
                String publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
                String publishdDate = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");
                String language = volumeInfo.getString("language");
                String pageCount = volumeInfo.getString("pageCount");
                String printType = volumeInfo.getString("printType");
                String maturityRating = volumeInfo.getString("maturityRating");

                Books book = new Books(title, authors, publisher, publishdDate, language, pageCount, printType, maturityRating);
                books.add(book);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return books;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are confused about the maturity rating why? That is how it is stored in the JSON. Also, you may find Gson to be a really useful library

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `String authors = volumeInfo.getString("authors");`

Because authors is an array you need to use `getJSONArray` instead of `getString` as below:

```
JSONArray authorsArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
```

This will get you the array of authors, but as you have simple `String` type in Book bean, you need to prepare the a string with appending all authors as below.

BookUtils code snippet to handle the array of authors:

```
for(int i = 0; i < booksArray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject currentBook = booksArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
        JSONArray authorsArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
        String authors = "";
        for(int i=0; i<authorsArray.length();i++) {
            authors = authors +","+authorsArray.getString(i);
        }

        //set the other strings as is

        Books book = new Books(title, authors, publisher, publishdDate, language, pageCount, printType, maturityRating);
        books.add(book);
    }
```

Comment: Its giving me an error in the constructor and the getter method.

Comment: I think writing "getString(i);" is a better solution since its in a for loop.

Comment: what's the error you are getting ? I have added Books code, look at it

Comment: The member variables in the constructor and the constructor paremeters are "incompatible types".

Comment: Did you look at me Book code above which has constructor for array os String authors ?

Comment: Ok sorry.  i ddin't look closer at that but your solution causes a problem in BookAdapter.java in the TextView authors = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        authors.setText(currentBook.getAuthors()); section

Comment: Can you look my code now, this gives , separated strings of authors ? Revert the Book code back to original.

Comment: it did.  Thanks a lot.